# How to proof the safety of traffic lights?

Tags: logic

Imagine I'm planning the traffic lights for a certain part of town. I want to be sure that everybody can rely on the traffic lights, not just "mostly", but fully.

How to formally proof that the traffic-light-circuit-algorithm is correct?

Imagine my part of town has multiple types of crossings:

```
---- ROAD ---- | | -----

         |
         |
---------x-----------
         |
         |

         |
         |
---------x-----------
```

The simplest case I guess is no traffic light at all. This should be easy to proof. But how about crossings with, let's say, $n$ roads?

What about crossings where cars from two or more roads can safely have green at the same time? How to specify that in terms of formal logic?

Comment: What do you mean rely on the traffic lights?  What sort of algorithm are you thinking about?  Typically you just define that the light is green in one direction and red in the other.

Comment: In engineering terms this would be a algorithm design based on some sort of well defined state transition model; though this could quickly become quite complicated for large n road junctions. With all the failure states added such as power fail, power brownout, lamp fail etc., this is too complex a system for formal proof. Formal safety analysis (statistical analysis most often) will generally be restricted to a set of simple interlocks (designed to work independently from the much more complex control algorithm) to try to prevent pre-identified unsafe or hazardous states from occurring.

Comment: The first and most important thing you need to do is model the **correctness property** that the algorithm is required to meet. If you have no definition of "correct", you can't prove correctness.